# How to fill an array with different random numbers from 1000 to 9999?

Tags: delphi, random

I'm trying to fill an array with different numbers from 1000 to 9999.

My problem is that my code is filling the array with the same number. Here is my approach:

```
repeat
  Write('Enter an Integer from 5 to 20: '); Readln(n)
until (n in [5..20]);

for i := 1 to n do 
begin
  T[i] := Random(9000)+1000; // 1000 to 9999
  Randomize
end;

Writeln('___________________________________');
for i := 1 to n do 
  Write(T[i], ' | '  );
Writeln;    
Writeln('___________________________________');
```

Comment: You must call `Randomize` BEFORE you call `Random` the first time. Also, you only need to call `Randomize` ONCE. Let `Randomize` be the first call your program does, and then don't call it again.

Comment: It resolved my problem, can you please give me an explanation if possible?

Comment: It's well explained [in the documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Randomize) and at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).

Comment: I got my answer, thank you sir!
I leave this mention here for the rest of vistors : `Do not combine the call to Randomize in a loop with calls to the Random function. Typically, Randomize is called only once, before all calls to Random.`

Comment: If you are using Delphi then you can find two more useful functions for dealing with random number generation in Math unit. One is [RandomRange](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Math.RandomRange) that allows you to randomly pick a number from within specified rage. So in your case you would simply call `X := RandomRange(1000,9999);`. Another function that could be useful is [RandomFrom](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Math.RandomFrom) to which you can pas an array of existing numbers to chose from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `Randomize()` before the actual loop:

```
Randomize();
for i := 1 to n do
begin
  T[i] := Random(9000) + 1000;
end;
```

> Randomize initializes the random number generator

Comment: It's worth explaining that initializing the random number generator with the same seed will reset the random number generator and it will generate the same sequence of random numbers again.  If you only read the first random number and then reinitialize each time then you will read the same "random" number (the first in the sequence) every single time.

Comment: If you are using modern Delphi version and have VCL application you actually doesn't have to call `Randomize`. Why? Because it is already called once in `System.IOUtils.TPath.Create` which is called during application initialization.. But this still holds true for Console applications.

Comment: @SilverWarior It is not because it is not needed that it shouldn't be done. if TPath.Create ever stop calling Randomize, or stop being called itself, that could "break" the application.  If you REALLY want to optimize it, you could probably do `if RandSeed <> 0 then Randomize;`